# GAE LoginAuthorization issue (not directed to WEB-INF)

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I have OpenID login in GAE:

```
private static final Map<String, String> openIdProviders;
    static {
        openIdProviders = new HashMap<String, String>();
        openIdProviders.put("Google", "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id");
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

        Principal princ = req.getUserPrincipal();
        Set<String> attributes = new HashSet<String>();

        String provider =req.getParameter("openIdProvider");
            for (String providerName : openIdProviders.keySet()) {
                String providerUrl = openIdProviders.get(providerName);
                if(providerName.equals(provider)){
                    String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL("/test/manager.jsp", null, providerUrl, attributes);
                    resp.sendRedirect(loginUrl);
                    return;

                }

            }
        }
```

**Everything Works greate!**

BUT I need to redirect to **WEB-INF/test/manager.jsp**

I know that I cant do this without RequestDispatcher.

**1 QUESTION** when I use RequestDispatcher  for loginUrl :

```
RequestDispatcher dispatch = req.getRequestDispatcher(loginUrl);  
                dispatch.forward(req, resp);
```

I have error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LoginCookieUtils.encodeEmailAsUserId(LoginCookieUtils.java:91)
```

**Quesiton 2.**
Then I try another sulotuion (redirect to the servlet. in this UserProfilePanel  servlet I' will use RequestDispatcher .

```
    String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL("/UserProfilePanel", null, providerUrl, attributes);                    
 resp.sendRedirect(loginUrl);
```

But, I have then that error:

Problem accessing /UserProfilePanel. Reason:

```
    Response has already been committed
Caused by:

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been committed
        at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:153)
```

I was testing at localhost: I was tedirected to **localhost:8888/_ah/login?continue=/FUserProfilePanel** when I enter my mail, error of "Response has already been committed".

**what can I do? I cant find solutions**

Answer (score -1):

in a remember, things in WEB-INF folder couldn't be served like you seems to want to do.

Try to put you test.jsp file somewhere "normal" ( root or in a subfolder of root)

Comment: I dont want someone to have access to this page. So I need WEB-INF

Comment: someone is client, who try to open page whithout server side redirection!